# Visual Studio 2013 not Syntax Checking js files

Tags: javascript, syntax, visual-studio-2013, intellisense

Visual Studio 2013 isn't verifying .js files.

I have a separate .js file under a Scripts folder, that is then referenced in my ASPX page.

The intellisense works when the script is within an html page or a .aspx page, but not in a .js file.

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Hi Erik if you found an answer please add it as answer and accept it, don't edit an answer into your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to get intellisense to work with js files referenced on your web pag you need to add a _reference.js file. It really doesn't matter where you put the file, but generally it should be placed along with the rest of your js files. Perhaps in a SCRIPTS folder.

Here is a good article explaining it in further detail.

For More Info: (http://gurustop.net/blog/2012/03/03/javascript-js-intellisense-auto_complete-in-visual-studio-11-beta-the-web-_references-js-file)

Comment: Aaron, have you tried?  If not then please reserve the snide comments.